# Web API JSON string result contains double quotes around value for dynamic object

Tags: json, dynamic, asp.net-web-api, odata

My controller is as follows...

```
public IHttpActionResult GetData()
    {
       IEnumerable<dynamic> result = api.getData();

       string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
       return Ok(json);
}
```

returns raw text from fiddler

{"@odata.context":"https://localhost:44305/api/$metadata#Edm.String","value":"[\r\n  {\r\n    \"UserName\": \"test@gmail.com\"\r\n  }\r\n]"

You notice the JSON object for value has double quotes around it and the special characters \r\n. How do I get it to return pure JSON format???

Comment: Why would you expect anything different?  You did serialize `result` to JSON string after all.  At the point `json` is just a string.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting more details from your code but have you tried this way.
Is there any specific reason to use a serialized object?

```html
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]                
        public IEnumerable<XYZ> GetData()
        {
            return api.GetData();
        }
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's by design since you are returning a json string..

Do this in js: JSON.parse(response.data)